# Getting RSSI value using J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, midlet, rssi

I am developing an application where I need to retrieve the RSSI value of a remote device.

I'm using J2ME, and I was wondering if exists a specific API or function that can help me with my problem.

Do anyone have a suggestion to gave me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'd check the [JSR 272](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=272) *Mobile Broadcast API*

> ...The API is targeted for CLDC/MIDP based mobile terminals... this set of API allows clients to:... Access to parameters that... include: network information, **signal strength**, ...